# How to I disable the link for the title inside a List View webpart?

Tags: list, list-view-web-part

How do I remove the link from the `'Pending Registrations'` title and also the `'Contoso Training Budget'` title?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just manage to find the answer as follows:

Select the list view web part and modify it and remove the 'Title URL' under the 'Advanced' section will do.

Reference: http://intl.feedfury.com/content/16270498-how-to-remove-the-web-part-title-bar-link.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on Advanced, simply replace the URL with a pound sign - #